How to capture environment variable passed during run time from Docker in Angular project
In my Docker desktop I want to find some way to capture environment variable passed at run time like in this screenshot:
docker-desktop
I want to pass multiple variables needed in the project, I can't hard-code them in my project as they vary a lot.
I tried different methods provided online, but they all failed and ended with problems
I'm using Angular v17.4
